# DataStax DevCenter stuck on Startup

Tags: datastax, datastax-startup

I just installed DataStax DevCenter. However when loading up, the Automatic Update & Usage page pops up. However the "Ok" button is disabled and unclickable. So I can't get pass the startup loading of the application. How can I bypass this?

[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohygo.png)

Answer (score 7):

This sounds very much like a known issue with DevCenter and Java versions 1.8.0_152 or Java 9.

Are you using either of those? Use `java -version` on the command line to quickly check which version is being used.

The only workaround at this time is to use a different version of Java - version 1.8.0_151 or earlier should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple JDKs and configure DevCenter to use earlier one.

Right-click on DevCenter.app in your properties directory
Click “Show package contents”
Open Contents/info.plist in an editor of your choice
Then, at the bottom you will find configuration that looks like the following:

```
<dict>
    <!-- a lot of stuff above -->
    <key>Eclipse</key>
    <array>
        <!-- comments on how to change the Java version -->
        <string>-keyring</string><string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
        <string>-showlocation</string>
        <!-- some more comments -->
    </array>
</dict>
```

Into the array element, insert the following children and make sure to adapt the old Java version you want DevCenter to use and your users name.

```
<string>-vm</string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.141.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```

Comment: Note, if you did `brew install adoptopenjdk8`, you would now add the line `<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>`

Comment: Opening tag for string in jdk path is missing in the answer. e.g.
<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>

Answer (score 1):

For me just changing the JAVA_HOME point to 1.8.0_151 did not work. Only after completely removing all other Java versions from machine, fixed the issue for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Changing to Java version _131 worked for me.